# Crossbrowser solution for disable/enable scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Long time ago I found somewhere (on stackoverflow I think) code to scroll one window height per scroll. I tried many libraries but that script works just like I want. But it's jumpy when scrolling during animation. So I disable scroll during animation but it works only in Firefox.

I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/msoys5gc/1/

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() < $(window).height() * 6 ) {
    window.onwheel = function(){ return false; };
}
$('html,body').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
  }, 600, function() {
    window.onwheel = function(){ return true; };
});
```

Comment: there is an [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/4146854) that working crossbrowser

Comment: CSS's scroll snapping my be interesting to you: http://blog.gospodarets.com/css-scroll-snap/ (They're not yet available in Chrome and are fairly new in Safari and Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t understand this:

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() < $(window).height() * 6 )
```

this will be true until you pass the six slide...

**UPDATED:** If you want to stop triggering the animation while it is running you can just delete the [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/). Then if you don't want to enqueue animations(and then get strange behaviors), you can just call [clearQueue()](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) when the animation has finished.

```js
var divs = $('.section'); 
var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
var div = 0; // current div

$(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
 if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
   dir = 'down';
  } 
  else {
   dir = 'up';
  }
  
  // find currently visible div :
  div = -1;
  divs.each(function(i){
   if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
    div = i;
   }
 });
  
  if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
   div--;
  }
  if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
   div++;
  }
  
  
 $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
  }, 1600, function() {
  $('html,body').clearQueue();
 });
  
  
  
  return false;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
 $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
});
```

```css
.section {
  height: 100vh;
}
body{
  margin: 0px !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" style="background: yellow;"></div>
<div class="section" style="background: green;"></div>
<div class="section" style="background: blue;"></div>
<div class="section" style="background: red;"></div>
<div class="section" style="background: violet;"></div>
<div class="section" style="background: orange;"></div>
<div class="section" style="background: black;"></div>
```